# $A$ , an $n\times n$ matrix has $k$ distinct eigenvalues, then the matrix $A^m$ for some $m>=0$ has the same eigenvalues raised to $m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I can prove that if $A$ has eigenvalues $a_1, a_2, .., a_k$, then $A^m$ has eigenvalues $a_1^m, a_2^m, ..., a_k^m$. How do I prove that these are the only eigenvalues $A^m$ has?

Suppose $A^m$$x = a_{k+1}x$ for some $x$. Then why is $a_{k+1}$ a power of one of the eigenvalues of $A$?

Thanks.

Edit : The field we are working over can be assumed to algebraically complete. (Or the complex plane, I don't want to focus on this too much)

Edit 2 : No knowledge of the Jordan form, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, you can write your matrix in its [Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). From the decomposition of $A$ in its Jordan from, the eigen values of $A^k$ become obvious.

**Edit.**

The Jordan form states (though I suggest a more detailed reading that this poor summary) that every matrix is similar to :

$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha_{1} & \ldots & a_{1}^{n}\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
0 & \ldots & \alpha_{n}
\end{array}\right)$

Where the $\alpha_i$ are its eigen values, the lower part is 0 and the upper part may be non zero. Now if you raise this matrix to a power $m$, you obtain the eigenvalues of $A^m$.

Now $A^m$ is similar to:

$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha_{1}^m & \ldots & b_{1}^{n}\\
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
0 & \ldots & \alpha_{n}^m
\end{array}\right)$

And :

$$\det(A^m-\lambda I)=(\alpha_1^m-\lambda)...(\alpha_n^m-\lambda)$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there an easy way to see why raising the upper triangular matrix to $m$ raises the diagonal entries to the power of $m$?

Comment: @Saad, yes, look at the characteristic polynomial of $A^m$, when it is expressed in its Jordan form

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(a_1-a)(a_2-a)...(a_n - a)$.. How do I get the characteristic polynomial of $A^m$?

Comment: @Saad I just added the information in the edit

Comment: But that's sort of what I'm asking. How do we know $A^m$ is similar to that matrix? All we know is that it is similar to some upper triangular matrix. We can work out that it is similar to that matrix by multiplying the upper triangular representation of $A$ by itself a couple times, but is there a way to see that the diagonal entries are raised to the power $m$ without doing the multiplication?

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof using more or less nothing, for matrices over an algebraically closed field:

Say $\sigma(A)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$. Then in fact for any polynomial $p$ we have $\sigma(p(A))=p(\sigma(A))$.

Proof: Suppose for notational convenience that $p$ is monic. Given a scalar $\lambda$ we can factor the polynomial $p(x)-\lambda$: $$p(x)-\lambda=\prod_{j=1}^n(x-\omega_j).$$So $$p(A)-\lambda I=\prod_1^n(A-\omega_jI).\quad(*)$$

> > Lemma: (For square matrices over any field.) $AB$ is invertible if and only  if $A$ and $B$ are both invertible.

Proof: If $A$ is not invertible then $A$ is not surjective (or rather of course the linear transformation defined by $A$ is not surjective), so $AB$ is not surjective. If $B$ is not invertible then $B$ is not injective, so $AB$ is not injective.

> > Corolllary:  $\prod_1^n A_j$ is invertible if and only if each $A_j$ is invertible.

Now if you apply the Corollary to (*) it shows that $\lambda\in\sigma(p(A))$ if and only if there exists $j$ so that $\omega_j\in\sigma(A)$. But $$\{\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n\}=\{\omega:p(\omega)=\lambda\},$$so we've shown that $\lambda\in\sigma(p(A))$ if and only if there exists $\omega\in\sigma(A)$ with $\lambda=p(\omega)$. Which is exactly what it means to say $\sigma(p(A))=p(\sigma(A))$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how the result follows from this.. also, what does the first sentence mean (with the $p$)

Comment: $\sigma(p(A)) = p(\sigma(A))=\{p(\omega):\omega\in\sigma(A))$. (For example, if $p(t)=t^2$ this says that the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are exactly the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$.) What part don't you see?

Comment: Why does $σ(p(A))=p(σ(A))$ imply anything about the eigenvalues of $A^m$?

Comment: Let $p(t)=t^m$. Then $\sigma(p(A))$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A^m$, while $p(\sigma(A))$ is the set of all numbers $\omega^m$, where $\omega$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. So $\sigma(p(A))=p(\sigma(A))$, for that polynomial, says precisely that the eigenvalues of $A^m$ are the same as the $m$th powers of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Thank you. And could you explain how the corollary implies that the sets are equal?

Comment: You know that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible, right? So the corollary, applied to ($*$), shows that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$ if and only if there exists $j$ such that $\omega_j$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. The equation just above ($*$) shows that $\lambda=p(\omega_j)$. _So_ every eigenvalue of $p(A)$ is of the form $p(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. The converse, that if $\omega$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $p(\omega)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A)$, is trivial: If $Ax=\omega x$ then $p(A)x=p(\omega)x$.

Answer (score 0):

This not true if the field is not algebraically closed, take for example $\mathbb{R}$, $A=\pmatrix{0&-1\cr 1&0}$ it does not has a real eigenvalue, but $A^2=-I$. If you suppose that the field is algebraically closed, you can find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is an upper triangular matrix, then $(PAP^{-1}), ^p=PA^pP^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with jordan forms. Is there a different way to see it?

Comment: There exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is a superior triangular matrix.

Comment: Does superior mean upper? If so, yes I am aware of that result. How do we use it to prove the result?

Comment: Added some additional assumptions.

Comment: Actually $\pmatrix{0&1\cr 1&0}$ has two real eigenvalues...